# Metadata for paper maps

Tags: metadata, geonetwork, iso-19115

In GeoNetwork/ISO 19115, how do you describe physical access parameters for a physical paper map (i.e. of type CI_PresentationFormCode==mapHardcopy)?

For example I want to be able to find the map through a room number, archive box and signature number associated to the map. Also interesting would be to store the size (A0, A1, ...) or weight.

Storing online resources works quite well with GeoNetwork and is good documented, for example you can enter a online location (URL) via CI_OnlineResource, But what about physical parameters of "hardware" maps? Are there other standards than ISO19115 that are better suited for physical maps?

**Clarification:** I'm aware that in ISO-19115, one can define that a data **IS** a paper map by setting CI_Citation.presentationForm to mapHardcopy (an element from the CodeList CI_PresentationFormCode). But: If my data is a paper map, how do I describe properties of
it that are very specific to paper maps:

- weight
- size
- book shelf
- material health
- library number

The only thing I can imagine is the library number which is storable in CI_Citation.identifier. What about the others?

Comment: I think you are correct that there is no way of adding this information explicitly in the ISO 19115 model.  For our ISO  19139 metadata of paper materials, we just use the abstract like _This is a collection of extracts from British newspapers describing earthquakes, mostly British. It contains original clippings, photocopies, and in a few cases manual transcriptions..._ If you need to publish ISO 19115/19139 with your additional information you could look though to extend the model and add the information/data structure you want/need. Perhaps with [MARCXML](http://goo.gl/RLXevM)?

Answer (score 2):

There are Eleven Editors for ISO 19115

http://www.fgdc.gov/metadata/iso-metadata-editor-review

2 Support other Data Storage.

Have successful used QR codes to maintain metadata and paper document for a large project - http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_wizard.html

It can be used with a mobile/cell phone without the need on a PC (apart from the original capture and storage of the metadata)

Comment: QR codes for georeferencing... https://sites.google.com/site/marcpfister/georeferencingwithqrcodes

Answer (score 0):

The [North American Profile of ISO19115](http://www.fgdc.gov/standards/projects/incits-l1-standards-projects/NAP-Metadata/napMetadataProfileV11_7-26-07.pdf/view) is helpful in this situation (and free!). For your specific question, look for the [codelist](http://www.geoconnections.org/developersCorner/nap/metadata/register/codelists.html) for CI_OnlineResource. The entry for a [hardcopy map is here](http://www.geoconnections.org/developersCorner/nap/metadata/register/registerItems.html#RI_388).

Comment: This entry already exists in ISO-19119. What I'm looking for are more paper-specific properties. See my edit above.